# RxJava call disposable dispose()

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit, rx-java2, rx-android

I am using rxjava with retrofit. In the following code the subscribeOn() and observeOn() keeps running. The App terminates and launched by itself continuously.

```
disposable = api.getUsers("135")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                users -> showResult(users)
            })
```

If I dispose right after the above it won't fetch complete data. So my question is when to dispose dispoable or how to know when subscribeOn() and observeOn() has completed it's task.

Answer (score 3):

either you can `dispose` in `onDestroy()` of your `Activity`.

or you can use `DisposableSingleObserver` for good , like this :

```
Disposable disposable = yourApi.subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<String>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<String> values) {
            // work with the resulting values
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            // handle the error case
        }
    });
```

> and then after you use the result (in this example case when you no longer need the values(api response) you can call dispose

```
    disposable.dispose();
```

best place to dispose an observer will be in  `onDestory()` , this will be the place where you no longer will be needing api result:

```
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    disposable.dispose();
}
```

Comment: @abhishek-borikar hope this answer clears your doubt.

Comment: @abhishek-borikar feel free to accept the answer mate, as it solves your problem

Comment: You should call dispose() in onStop() instead of onDestroy(). Image a scenario where just after making the API call, your activity goes into the background. The activity might not have been destroyed at that time so you won't dispose the disposable. If the API returns the result at that time, you might encounter unexpected behaviors.

Comment: if you put dispose() in onStop() instead of onDetroy() you will have problems when the user back to the view, because, the information required will not be loaded , and you disposable has been disposed() . so, the best pleace is onDestroy()... example: load a new activity  immediately will call onStop() of the first activity